# Delayed warnings in R

Tags: r

I had an odd experience regarding warnings when I used R, version 3.5.0. The warnings come out after I already finished data manipulation. A while later - about 10 minutes later, the warnings for one data set appeared when I was manipulating another data set. At first, I thought I made some mistakes I was not aware of, and re-did everything. However, this kept happening.

So, I again re-did everything, and specifically typed warnings() after I finished the part that the warnings pointed to, and I got nothing, meaning there was no warnings. As expected, a while later, when I am manipulating some other data, the exactly same warnings come out!

Did anybody else encounter this also?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what did the warnings say?

Comment: What warning are you talking about?

Comment: the warnings supply 10000 data to 900 rows, and thus 100 was recycled.

Answer (score 1):

Under `?options` you see:

> warn:
>   sets the handling of warning messages. If warn is negative all warnings are ignored. If warn is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns. If 10 or fewer warnings were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how many were signalled. An object called last.warning is created and can be printed through the function warnings. If warn is one, warnings are printed as they occur. If warn is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors.

So basically by default the warnings don't print until the top level function returns. If R thinks that a function is not done (a plotting function maybe) then it will wait to issue the warnings. Try entering `options(warn=1)` and re-running the code to see where the issue is.

Comment: I don't think it's because of this, since the two data sets even have different names. Manipulating on one is not supposed to affect the other.

Comment: But the `warn=1` should force the warning to be issued immediately - so that may give you a new clue.

Comment: Thanks. I re-did my data analysis, and tried options(warn=1) after the part that the warnings pointed to. R didn't give anything, just like I used warnings().

Comment: I just found what happened. I need to rbind two data sets. One is the main data, the other is supplementary. The supp. one is made by matrix, with no names. So, I used colnames(supp.)<-names(main), then use warnings(), and all the warnings, which are exactly the same as before, come out. I still don't know why yet.